# Use of List<? extends Object>

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I tried to run the below code

```
List<? extends Object> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1); //compile error
list.add("abb");//compile error
```

I understand we can't add anything to above list. Then what is the purpose of creating a list in this way ?

What is the reason java allowed us to create a list this way ?

Thanks

Comment: Wildcards should only really be used in method parameters to make the API accept a broader range of inputs. You should only rarely use them as local variables or fields.

Comment: "I understand we can't add anything to above list." Not true, you can add `null`.